# Geoserver fid with database spatial views

Tags: geoserver

I created a database spatial view that performs a certain query on a spatial PostGIS table (Parcels layer), the view is working well, and I published it via Geoserver, and everything went well, except that the feature id generated by geoserver (Parcels.fid) is displayed in a strange format NOT in integer format as with regular PostGIS tables published with Geoserver as shown in the attached image. What might be the issue here?

[image]

Comment: What you see means that GeoServer does not automatically detect the FID so it generates something that is at least very likely to be unique. Is the field that you use as FID in the main table also primary key?

Comment: Yes, its a primary key

Comment: And the primary key field is also selected into the database view that you then publish with GeoServer, or?

Answer (score 2):

If it's a database view, you need to tell GeoServer that there is indeed a field that can be used as a primary key, using a lookup table described here:
http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/data/database/primarykey.html

If instead it's a SQL View construct (you giving GeoServer a query to run) you have to do the same, but in a different way, see "identifier" in this page:
http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/data/database/sqlview.html

Comment: Also a materialised view can produce a correct fid as a materialised view can have a PK that is detected by geoserver. Materialised views does not suit every use case though.